How to a achieve consistent look when sending emarsys emails to a mobile device?
For some reason when I send a test email to my two email accounts (google account and work account), both of which are logged into gmail app on my Samsung phone I get very different results.
In my google account the email does not understand that it needs to show the mobile optimised version of the newsletter and in the work account it shows up very buggy and the buttons look very messed up.
google account view
work account view
I have tried @media only screen and (max-width:414px) and **@media only screen and (orientation: portrait)
**
but the google account still does not respond and the text looks very tiny.
Here is my code for the buttons
<e-optional name="CTA">
                  <tr>
                <td align="{variables.ctaAlign}" >  
                  <a href="" e-editable="url1_S4" target="_blank" style="text-decoration:none;">
                  <table cellpadding="0" cellspacing="0" valign="middle"  class="ctaStyle ctaBackground{variables.standardBlockBackgroundColour}">
                   <tr>
                   <td align="center" class="buttonPadding">                
                      <a href="" class="ctaStyle ctaBackground{variables.standardBlockBackgroundColour}" e-editable="url1_S4" target="_blank" class="CTAtext" style="border:0px; color:inherit; text-decoration:none;">  
                        <font e-editable="link_text1_S4" class="CTAtext" style="color:inherit;">
                         CTA LOREM IPSUM
                            </font></a>
                  </td>
                    
                    </table></a></td></tr> 
            </e-optional>

Any suggestions how to fix this would be great. Thanks

Have you looked at what CSS is supported in which email systems? And what system is your work email using? Using E.g. https://www.caniemail.com/ up can be helpful. For example some systems don’t fully support @media queries.

There are two main Gmail accounts. @gmail.com accounts, and accounts like business ones that use your own domain and connect via IMAP or POP to the Gmail application. These "Gmail IMAP" accounts have all <style> blocks stripped (deleted).
Furthermore, the standard gmail account may be experiencing tiny text because it's not properly responsive. For example, there might be a large image that doesn't have a max-width on it, or is not otherwise responsive. Or a long URL it can't move to the next line. Therefore, it's shrinking everything down to size and you get tiny text.
It's a big world out there with many quirks, a bit like the old Internet Exploder and Netscape Navigator days, but on steroids. You would need to either learn 20+ of the main email software clients, or use an email builder.
